# Stacking XRD plot using multiplot : Discussion on random texts appearing in eps terminal

Tags: gnuplot

[image]I wish to plot XRD patterns in a multiplot environment. The XRD patterns are plotted separately and they seem to be fine but the stacked plot shows random texts, symbols at various multiplots. Data file is given below.

```
# XRD 
15  117 182 176 189
15.05   129 207 186 166
15.1    129 213 158 144
15.15   137 156 159 167
15.2    148 191 179 150
15.25   116 202 176 142
15.3    162 206 153 139
15.35   125 184 129 147
15.4    130 180 146 150
15.45   145 212 134 137
15.5    119 193 166 127
15.55   118 195 152 161
15.6    148 201 150 131
15.65   122 188 152 154
15.7    121 172 142 155
15.75   125 163 129 141
15.8    121 180 123 151
15.85   124 170 134 135
15.9    118 197 126 147
15.95   135 185 153 142
16  127 161 154 162
16.05   126 196 155 151
16.1    105 184 146 157
16.15   123 191 133 128
16.2    115 185 128 130
16.25   143 184 140 126
16.3    112 164 178 135
16.35   119 174 123 136
16.4    113 168 130 133
16.45   111 188 123 143
16.5    120 179 109 165
16.55   113 156 131 128
16.6    105 175 153 136
16.65   119 170 114 143
16.7    117 155 151 143
16.75   112 144 141 130
16.8    116 153 142 148
16.85   128 166 121 137
16.9    119 136 124 152
16.95   91  160 111 124
17  95  153 123 125
17.05   119 140 133 133
17.1    112 140 134 127
17.15   114 152 118 129
17.2    123 164 113 139
17.25   106 155 134 120
17.3    114 153 121 120
17.35   100 151 118 142
17.4    105 152 119 152
17.45   86  127 117 133
17.5    105 156 118 129
17.55   90  150 117 143
17.6    94  137 116 117
17.65   104 150 95  118
17.7    102 140 89  129
17.75   99  146 114 128
17.8    123 142 115 126
17.85   93  146 149 128
17.9    90  147 125 135
17.95   86  121 102 136
18  91  123 110 124
18.05   99  117 103 140
18.1    106 125 88  138
18.15   93  124 91  118
18.2    94  138 100 133
18.25   108 108 115 110
18.3    97  122 111 118
18.35   92  132 90  124
18.4    88  130 101 129
18.45   94  120 112 118
18.5    108 124 94  150
18.55   100 118 105 110
18.6    87  136 134 112
18.65   121 107 85  130
18.7    94  131 101 124
18.75   86  134 104 117
18.8    108 138 107 122
18.85   101 133 112 113
18.9    83  112 88  126
18.95   94  107 123 123
19  83  137 110 123
19.05   85  136 102 137
19.1    107 110 82  122
19.15   82  121 92  118
19.2    84  128 114 141
19.25   94  109 103 108
19.3    81  119 102 105
19.35   96  119 95  112
19.4    84  82  86  120
19.45   88  105 97  106
19.5    119 114 91  134
19.55   77  91  102 125
19.6    84  124 108 133
19.65   73  117 92  121
19.7    86  119 104 134
19.75   75  125 84  135
19.8    108 122 80  121
19.85   89  91  91  104
19.9    80  90  105 132
19.95   85  108 78  131
20  88  114 93  129
20.05   92  97  78  142
20.1    96  111 105 120
20.15   88  114 94  115
20.2    84  100 86  121
20.25   100 100 80  132
20.3    94  84  88  147
20.35   84  101 78  111
20.4    78  105 89  112
20.45   81  86  98  129
20.5    86  111 89  127
20.55   92  92  83  120
20.6    85  90  86  121
20.65   74  90  89  141
20.7    83  103 71  141
20.75   74  98  99  114
20.8    87  75  83  149
20.85   67  96  82  154
20.9    85  93  80  174
20.95   83  109 95  157
21  90  97  83  211
21.05   81  105 66  277
21.1    87  94  86  446
21.15   84  97  92  443
21.2    83  101 90  446
21.25   84  100 88  421
21.3    86  107 90  357
21.35   92  97  101 297
21.4    92  112 89  352
21.45   73  108 91  321
21.5    97  130 94  346
21.55   96  128 90  480
21.6    88  121 88  663
21.65   95  107 74  941
21.7    93  95  75  1106
21.75   83  83  67  1078
21.8    91  101 70  966
21.85   91  108 78  815
21.9    76  95  87  792
21.95   85  74  94  629
22  89  86  70  593
22.05   87  81  88  402
22.1    72  73  81  289
22.15   85  90  69  240
22.2    71  94  76  188
22.25   68  74  70  160
22.3    75  96  72  146
22.35   63  82  64  156
22.4    64  77  61  145
22.45   76  84  73  140
22.5    72  98  64  128
22.55   78  73  91  126
22.6    62  95  64  113
22.65   80  74  80  119
22.7    80  85  72  132
22.75   78  80  79  98
22.8    85  72  78  140
22.85   62  88  69  115
22.9    74  94  71  126
22.95   84  91  78  131
23  73  69  79  106
23.05   76  78  66  133
23.1    83  84  79  115
23.15   48  84  77  97
23.2    74  91  62  111
23.25   79  99  58  116
23.3    75  77  53  126
23.35   70  94  67  163
23.4    94  84  70  161
23.45   80  74  69  175
23.5    79  74  65  213
23.55   69  75  67  206
23.6    73  91  72  225
23.65   55  78  81  191
23.7    72  99  68  180
23.75   59  87  81  191
23.8    87  100 69  183
23.85   76  95  76  172
23.9    70  97  74  207
23.95   76  90  75  281
24  74  87  69  359
24.05   76  81  67  443
24.1    89  74  68  472
24.15   79  72  53  429
24.2    84  73  72  345
24.25   72  82  59  313
24.3    69  71  71  300
24.35   74  92  85  283
24.4    72  94  65  245
24.45   85  89  69  186
24.5    65  90  80  156
24.55   85  100 69  102
24.6    68  77  69  116
24.65   71  74  76  121
24.7    70  77  61  119
24.75   70  75  70  118
24.8    75  65  70  115
24.85   73  73  80  124
24.9    79  93  62  98
24.95   76  76  78  104
25  78  75  55  95
25.05   68  77  66  107
25.1    67  82  71  83
25.15   62  73  74  106
25.2    72  88  56  113
25.25   65  86  65  108
25.3    78  70  71  103
25.35   74  73  63  93
25.4    67  62  90  110
25.45   77  98  74  88
25.5    70  78  60  101
25.55   82  81  54  107
25.6    80  62  65  97
25.65   64  91  64  95
25.7    71  74  71  91
25.75   67  75  58  81
25.8    70  78  74  76
25.85   73  95  62  94
25.9    80  78  67  96
25.95   69  86  66  88
26  61  71  71  102
26.05   82  72  63  95
26.1    86  75  57  106
26.15   83  80  62  84
26.2    88  74  65  85
26.25   68  76  60  104
26.3    78  70  58  92
26.35   66  74  70  107
26.4    71  68  60  93
26.45   69  81  77  105
26.5    61  74  79  81
26.55   73  81  60  82
26.6    74  79  56  84
26.65   83  97  81  97
26.7    72  78  64  92
26.75   82  79  66  104
26.8    84  77  49  85
26.85   72  79  58  95
26.9    68  77  70  89
26.95   72  82  62  82
27  63  75  68  83
27.05   66  74  66  82
27.1    68  78  48  102
27.15   65  85  52  93
27.2    75  71  64  78
27.25   72  80  83  79
27.3    66  84  57  92
27.35   58  83  56  82
27.4    67  67  51  82
27.45   73  91  54  83
27.5    74  82  67  89
27.55   84  87  68  79
27.6    80  79  73  101
27.65   82  58  70  100
27.7    70  85  62  96
27.75   71  65  76  85
27.8    70  73  68  71
27.85   76  81  55  89
27.9    73  65  58  91
27.95   85  75  65  95
28  82  77  64  79
28.05   75  89  64  74
28.1    70  85  60  88
28.15   85  73  55  96
28.2    80  94  71  86
28.25   96  84  94  114
28.3    126 101 99  130
28.35   173 172 136 133
28.4    219 257 164 189
28.45   270 213 188 258
28.5    214 230 153 232
28.55   158 139 127 192
28.6    105 110 80  171
28.65   78  84  75  122
28.7    75  72  56  112
28.75   82  79  66  97
28.8    83  69  66  97
28.85   74  63  79  81
28.9    79  65  64  93
28.95   77  80  71  77
29  61  55  62  89
29.05   75  71  64  93
29.1    75  81  69  91
29.15   65  93  78  90
29.2    69  75  63  80
29.25   79  86  60  74
29.3    68  89  64  80
29.35   78  73  78  83
29.4    74  73  66  78
29.45   57  88  72  92
29.5    75  63  79  99
29.55   65  70  79  73
29.6    69  87  69  103
29.65   83  75  48  86
29.7    72  72  59  92
29.75   69  60  68  77
29.8    65  66  58  93
29.85   68  82  74  89
29.9    89  76  75  78
29.95   79  69  73  100
30  84  76  73  108
30.05   110 86  84  101
30.1    129 129 102 124
30.15   146 140 114 154
30.2    150 159 127 186
30.25   136 152 124 157
30.3    117 101 88  169
30.35   81  94  77  125
30.4    72  76  77  120
30.45   85  86  69  116
30.5    75  96  78  91
30.55   71  66  61  64
30.6    70  76  61  92
30.65   72  65  74  97
30.7    87  78  53  84
30.75   67  59  64  92
30.8    71  71  81  82
30.85   75  74  72  79
30.9    80  89  81  56
30.95   76  68  67  87
31  78  68  62  80
31.05   72  72  69  65
31.1    66  69  61  82
31.15   85  72  64  80
31.2    61  67  72  75
31.25   62  73  70  79
31.3    69  60  64  73
31.35   75  74  59  77
31.4    51  69  58  76
31.45   48  59  58  75
31.5    55  73  71  76
31.55   77  77  67  64
31.6    66  66  64  90
31.65   84  74  74  81
31.7    64  71  78  88
31.75   69  79  64  85
31.8    74  79  56  65
31.85   53  67  72  72
31.9    77  57  55  68
31.95   68  66  72  89
32  74  74  80  80
32.05   53  82  61  77
32.1    67  63  66  74
32.15   61  72  67  77
32.2    68  56  66  75
32.25   77  74  48  87
32.3    62  71  60  75
32.35   57  38  63  79
32.4    62  62  78  72
32.45   62  59  70  73
32.5    62  69  63  70
32.55   66  71  56  75
32.6    56  66  65  70
32.65   55  71  52  80
32.7    62  69  62  79
32.75   61  75  68  75
32.8    67  76  66  66
32.85   74  66  63  71
32.9    49  87  78  83
32.95   66  64  71  65
33  82  75  74  86
33.05   57  50  74  88
33.1    59  68  60  77
33.15   61  73  66  77
33.2    62  62  82  70
33.25   74  67  62  85
33.3    60  71  76  72
33.35   72  63  52  70
33.4    66  56  66  77
33.45   71  64  55  74
33.5    58  61  42  66
33.55   66  58  52  79
33.6    59  53  52  69
33.65   66  60  46  76
33.7    53  73  51  84
33.75   70  65  66  71
33.8    52  52  49  73
33.85   66  66  86  74
33.9    58  78  62  82
33.95   65  65  63  87
34  47  53  62  75
34.05   51  63  60  80
34.1    56  77  53  74
34.15   55  53  64  69
34.2    77  49  53  63
34.25   70  82  61  86
34.3    64  69  52  52
34.35   59  67  51  73
34.4    62  77  70  71
34.45   51  58  73  65
34.5    62  78  65  55
34.55   48  69  66  74
34.6    45  70  52  66
34.65   59  72  68  77
34.7    65  62  56  69
34.75   64  68  58  64
34.8    83  73  78  75
34.85   75  112 74  88
34.9    125 136 92  95
34.95   149 139 104 120
35  152 129 103 125
35.05   120 142 97  140
35.1    84  104 80  104
35.15   76  66  76  94
35.2    70  84  70  99
35.25   63  67  60  74
35.3    68  60  62  88
35.35   51  70  52  78
35.4    64  57  62  63
35.45   62  56  43  66
35.5    58  71  63  62
35.55   63  66  57  80
35.6    67  53  57  63
35.65   68  56  59  61
35.7    62  49  46  67
35.75   58  55  66  82
35.8    59  49  49  63
35.85   48  70  57  73
35.9    53  45  47  58
35.95   55  64  43  72
36  54  52  46  71
36.05   56  68  51  74
36.1    49  59  62  96
36.15   53  56  49  93
36.2    66  57  59  92
36.25   60  60  49  99
36.3    63  62  52  113
36.35   61  59  57  102
36.4    48  61  51  107
36.45   67  53  45  81
36.5    61  59  65  84
36.55   50  62  42  101
36.6    48  57  51  72
36.65   46  67  59  66
36.7    70  63  54  86
36.75   54  61  55  61
36.8    62  63  40  61
36.85   62  52  60  51
36.9    45  69  43  77
36.95   56  59  45  71
37  44  73  50  72
37.05   59  58  53  64
37.1    58  42  42  48
37.15   53  52  53  57
37.2    49  64  51  52
37.25   49  54  45  54
37.3    54  56  56  62
37.35   51  50  64  64
37.4    48  68  44  67
37.45   49  58  46  61
37.5    56  45  63  64
37.55   47  51  37  55
37.6    53  60  51  79
37.65   50  46  45  69
37.7    47  45  44  60
37.75   48  45  53  68
37.8    64  60  46  65
37.85   61  45  41  71
37.9    56  57  45  66
37.95   44  54  55  70
38  44  43  51  72
38.05   43  52  48  73
38.1    45  52  46  48
38.15   51  57  34  66
38.2    61  59  50  70
38.25   48  57  53  65
38.3    39  51  46  62
38.35   58  48  43  58
38.4    50  57  45  71
38.45   56  57  55  70
38.5    49  54  45  59
38.55   54  49  65  85
38.6    47  47  48  60
38.65   47  49  65  78
38.7    46  45  54  73
38.75   49  55  56  78
38.8    43  50  51  64
38.85   50  51  46  79
38.9    51  51  45  75
38.95   60  44  50  56
39  69  51  64  60
39.05   46  49  46  61
39.1    68  47  42  78
39.15   44  61  44  79
39.2    42  39  46  66
39.25   46  48  45  72
39.3    52  55  48  75
39.35   43  62  44  65
39.4    46  55  47  60
39.45   52  55  48  78
39.5    57  49  50  68
39.55   46  58  54  68
39.6    48  51  41  80
39.65   47  53  53  81
39.7    51  48  43  78
39.75   61  57  51  78
39.8    48  55  45  83
39.85   53  43  64  80
39.9    59  52  55  77
39.95   46  47  46  69
40  53  57  38  83
40.05   51  48  51  79
40.1    49  50  47  66
40.15   56  40  48  71
40.2    49  62  51  91
40.25   50  65  52  91
40.3    52  72  56  87
40.35   58  61  64  109
40.4    62  63  95  83
40.45   99  89  84  105
40.5    119 127 112 112
40.55   161 160 161 185
40.6    135 183 185 206
40.65   163 176 168 220
40.7    130 158 136 213
40.75   105 119 107 190
40.8    80  80  57  168
40.85   68  67  66  125
40.9    53  71  42  110
40.95   55  65  48  100
41  53  48  58  91
41.05   54  53  52  83
41.1    59  50  53  73
41.15   56  56  59  71
41.2    53  57  56  72
41.25   52  49  50  69
41.3    46  51  46  65
41.35   47  56  45  73
41.4    44  46  60  75
41.45   57  56  55  69
41.5    49  47  31  72
41.55   48  45  50  74
41.6    42  54  50  83
41.65   45  59  56  76
41.7    46  44  39  76
41.75   48  53  47  69
41.8    44  62  51  56
41.85   51  51  44  74
41.9    45  57  38  85
41.95   54  44  39  81
42  44  61  46  72
42.05   46  52  41  72
42.1    43  53  35  90
42.15   53  50  50  73
42.2    50  49  58  88
42.25   38  41  55  82
42.3    42  51  46  61
42.35   51  33  42  77
42.4    51  51  59  59
42.45   42  35  46  80
42.5    36  45  44  80
42.55   36  39  47  76
42.6    53  46  66  76
42.65   44  45  50  79
42.7    38  41  43  76
42.75   45  34  31  63
42.8    55  58  50  84
42.85   33  46  42  78
42.9    50  46  43  70
42.95   58  55  58  66
43  48  48  52  72
43.05   46  61  65  81
43.1    51  47  41  77
43.15   44  57  40  74
43.2    58  63  41  80
43.25   47  47  45  73
43.3    47  38  47  79
43.35   59  43  49  70
43.4    42  53  33  78
43.45   50  43  43  59
43.5    50  51  67  62
43.55   45  45  52  89
43.6    48  48  57  74
43.65   51  57  38  62
43.7    38  37  42  84
43.75   51  63  47  80
43.8    57  44  50  93
43.85   49  50  45  93
43.9    59  54  37  93
43.95   40  48  34  77
44  41  63  39  87
44.05   39  50  56  75
44.1    37  49  53  90
44.15   43  49  48  59
44.2    43  59  52  60
44.25   52  60  41  78
44.3    50  44  52  71
44.35   46  47  49  70
44.4    41  44  37  65
44.45   48  45  47  55
44.5    44  46  44  78
44.55   40  42  33  76
44.6    47  58  40  64
44.65   39  49  51  64
44.7    49  48  42  74
44.75   49  62  47  65
44.8    44  48  49  61
44.85   38  53  46  73
44.9    44  41  37  59
44.95   53  47  32  60
45  46  39  44  62
45.05   51  52  32  62
45.1    31  42  49  63
45.15   38  49  41  66
45.2    51  57  46  63
45.25   42  46  38  60
45.3    47  53  46  59
45.35   46  49  45  64
45.4    37  59  45  61
45.45   66  40  46  62
45.5    53  53  45  67
45.55   40  52  36  63
45.6    45  56  48  62
45.65   39  49  42  62
45.7    47  39  45  71
45.75   39  41  54  58
45.8    45  52  42  66
45.85   38  50  38  57
45.9    48  55  43  56
45.95   42  55  45  52
46  35  49  30  59
46.05   46  57  53  58
46.1    45  41  37  60
46.15   34  39  44  55
46.2    55  45  44  65
46.25   39  53  39  63
46.3    35  52  53  61
46.35   50  38  43  55
46.4    32  47  27  67
46.45   49  45  53  49
46.5    50  49  50  59
46.55   36  56  42  70
46.6    46  44  49  54
46.65   51  56  42  64
46.7    41  50  37  63
46.75   41  54  45  55
46.8    53  43  49  51
46.85   54  51  55  54
46.9    50  55  22  64
46.95   43  51  35  58
47  44  47  39  57
47.05   61  57  31  60
47.1    36  43  35  61
47.15   43  42  49  77
47.2    48  49  48  59
47.25   38  41  47  71
47.3    46  49  39  70
47.35   48  59  36  66
47.4    51  40  30  47
47.45   42  42  39  72
47.5    51  55  43  65
47.55   37  36  44  64
47.6    40  49  51  64
47.65   49  41  40  48
47.7    33  41  50  60
47.75   36  46  44  60
47.8    41  51  50  64
47.85   49  48  54  76
47.9    39  39  45  64
47.95   42  53  50  52
48  58  58  38  41
48.05   51  37  51  60
48.1    43  40  51  76
48.15   48  46  50  51
48.2    46  49  42  55
48.25   34  58  37  45
48.3    44  49  26  66
48.35   39  63  54  68
48.4    44  48  47  61
48.45   46  48  46  61
48.5    35  49  36  63
48.55   35  46  39  61
48.6    51  48  44  55
48.65   43  61  53  52
48.7    45  61  50  51
48.75   54  38  45  53
48.8    48  59  52  69
48.85   41  60  50  68
48.9    49  50  41  54
48.95   52  52  49  62
49  36  51  42  59
49.05   42  58  48  57
49.1    38  43  41  44
49.15   44  57  51  56
49.2    44  46  45  71
49.25   38  57  41  58
49.3    49  57  28  69
49.35   54  39  44  63
49.4    52  54  52  50
49.45   39  56  45  59
49.5    41  51  58  58
49.55   66  58  63  57
49.6    51  44  58  76
49.65   38  51  50  54
49.7    34  60  52  55
49.75   52  51  51  47
49.8    46  51  53  53
49.85   60  55  52  51
49.9    47  47  55  54
49.95   45  54  39  57
50  68  73  58  55
50.05   66  86  50  70
50.1    68  87  79  78
50.15   89  98  114 75
50.2    133 156 143 105
50.25   137 152 160 169
50.3    125 162 185 162
50.35   124 141 121 132
50.4    103 113 105 127
50.45   88  78  77  118
50.5    72  74  66  72
50.55   59  65  54  60
50.6    56  57  55  62
50.65   46  46  56  58
50.7    39  53  45  57
50.75   51  57  57  53
50.8    27  58  41  52
50.85   45  53  34  62
50.9    41  54  60  50
50.95   43  55  40  47
51  51  49  52  68
51.05   49  51  47  51
51.1    45  64  54  51
51.15   38  48  52  51
51.2    48  43  48  50
51.25   43  57  37  59
51.3    42  40  54  55
51.35   44  39  63  57
51.4    45  50  41  46
51.45   49  44  58  52
51.5    40  51  56  57
51.55   43  40  56  59
51.6    37  42  42  72
51.65   50  47  53  47
51.7    47  43  48  61
51.75   37  57  44  60
51.8    39  59  46  65
51.85   43  62  42  70
51.9    42  47  41  60
51.95   40  51  41  65
52  45  45  64  56
52.05   34  44  58  61
52.1    32  43  70  62
52.15   43  49  58  62
52.2    37  50  47  66
52.25   47  52  43  82
52.3    62  42  58  62
52.35   36  49  54  62
52.4    45  44  41  67
52.45   36  48  37  68
52.5    37  48  52  65
52.55   38  46  50  63
52.6    37  47  59  62
52.65   35  43  45  56
52.7    38  52  49  69
52.75   47  47  47  66
52.8    40  38  47  67
52.85   50  54  47  62
52.9    50  50  38  56
52.95   44  40  54  59
53  44  58  30  63
53.05   35  56  54  53
53.1    46  43  48  43
53.15   43  49  52  57
53.2    40  40  40  56
53.25   57  47  47  63
53.3    29  45  38  57
53.35   39  49  56  63
53.4    39  38  50  66
53.45   43  44  48  64
53.5    51  52  43  65
53.55   44  61  42  51
53.6    53  59  45  63
53.65   40  57  50  62
53.7    41  56  47  50
53.75   59  23  47  66
53.8    46  47  35  57
53.85   46  42  47  67
53.9    57  60  42  53
53.95   52  43  50  62
54  48  52  44  60
54.05   50  50  31  57
54.1    40  50  54  55
54.15   42  45  43  38
54.2    46  52  47  59
54.25   48  45  40  54
54.3    47  42  44  49
54.35   42  45  47  53
54.4    49  48  47  55
54.45   43  42  48  54
54.5    43  50  49  54
54.55   54  45  41  57
54.6    44  53  42  59
54.65   40  47  41  45
54.7    45  35  49  58
54.75   34  37  47  52
54.8    42  53  45  48
54.85   40  58  41  56
54.9    34  50  47  51
54.95   43  42  37  53
55  51  51  59  63
55.05   56  55  48  55
55.1    42  37  42  39
55.15   37  48  39  67
55.2    41  52  41  61
55.25   49  52  47  61
55.3    53  39  40  71
55.35   46  51  40  61
55.4    47  51  44  53
55.45   39  43  34  57
55.5    43  49  54  57
55.55   43  40  40  58
55.6    41  37  56  57
55.65   38  50  41  56
55.7    36  51  35  56
55.75   55  47  43  62
55.8    45  51  45  59
55.85   37  56  40  45
55.9    47  47  45  54
55.95   50  36  44  44
56  46  44  54  52
56.05   51  47  43  58
56.1    51  48  45  53
56.15   56  42  32  65
56.2    31  43  46  63
56.25   44  53  47  47
56.3    41  35  35  54
56.35   45  49  43  55
56.4    45  47  34  54
56.45   49  44  40  56
56.5    45  45  49  59
56.55   60  61  59  65
56.6    30  52  53  50
56.65   38  51  46  57
56.7    51  54  53  39
56.75   54  54  46  36
56.8    45  39  51  63
56.85   38  55  45  57
56.9    40  57  43  56
56.95   41  38  45  58
57  36  42  37  69
57.05   35  60  45  49
57.1    45  47  38  48
57.15   41  39  46  47
57.2    49  51  42  67
57.25   36  42  29  51
57.3    38  40  29  52
57.35   43  47  45  53
57.4    43  62  32  57
57.45   41  41  45  69
57.5    42  54  39  53
57.55   42  52  30  65
57.6    41  40  47  71
57.65   39  42  45  49
57.7    37  52  53  56
57.75   48  58  38  44
57.8    42  54  51  53
57.85   56  47  35  47
57.9    45  41  30  46
57.95   39  44  54  59
58  51  32  40  53
58.05   40  39  41  60
58.1    47  47  33  41
58.15   39  46  40  59
58.2    46  51  51  41
58.25   37  52  48  58
58.3    41  37  45  49
58.35   36  48  43  44
58.4    50  44  45  54
58.45   42  45  44  41
58.5    58  56  47  58
58.55   36  51  48  52
58.6    59  54  57  74
58.65   57  63  60  72
58.7    57  75  65  68
58.75   68  74  81  79
58.8    61  60  53  77
58.85   68  74  62  94
58.9    58  67  53  67
58.95   54  44  42  67
59  53  39  42  71
59.05   59  47  39  63
59.1    48  38  45  55
59.15   49  48  57  49
59.2    42  52  49  46
59.25   49  41  45  54
59.3    45  52  41  46
59.35   38  48  50  47
59.4    44  50  38  51
59.45   54  55  61  57
59.5    37  49  54  59
59.55   52  66  62  61
59.6    62  65  54  57
59.65   70  87  82  79
59.7    73  97  82  74
59.75   88  87  79  84
59.8    69  97  61  83
59.85   62  71  67  67
59.9    60  55  72  78
59.95   51  56  44  60
60  59  59  52  51
60.05   51  48  57  48
60.1    45  54  48  55
60.15   45  49  38  53
60.2    39  45  45  50
60.25   55  43  39  60
60.3    48  40  38  52
60.35   45  40  55  51
60.4    34  44  35  59
60.45   47  38  39  49
60.5    32  48  53  44
60.55   40  41  51  36
60.6    40  44  36  55
60.65   54  44  55  55
60.7    35  46  29  49
60.75   50  47  37  46
60.8    40  45  40  68
60.85   34  51  54  48
60.9    39  40  63  50
60.95   31  58  39  46
61  27  46  37  43
61.05   45  55  47  46
61.1    47  42  52  48
61.15   41  45  42  60
61.2    34  43  49  47
61.25   46  40  47  57
61.3    42  43  35  51
61.35   33  46  37  62
61.4    45  39  54  50
61.45   41  54  58  56
61.5    31  48  57  49
61.55   42  44  47  49
61.6    40  52  37  52
61.65   32  48  42  76
61.7    35  36  48  59
61.75   33  51  28  46
61.8    45  47  42  50
61.85   48  48  40  55
61.9    50  37  40  41
61.95   44  50  39  41
62  36  31  48  51
62.05   34  51  38  28
62.1    44  48  40  48
62.15   47  43  43  52
62.2    40  45  40  58
62.25   42  40  47  60
62.3    50  35  44  51
62.35   51  57  41  56
62.4    43  58  52  70
62.45   46  51  55  38
62.5    59  64  58  65
62.55   50  52  47  53
62.6    56  72  62  61
62.65   63  57  57  68
62.7    67  68  55  83
62.75   54  72  60  61
62.8    61  57  54  67
62.85   54  53  53  55
62.9    43  50  49  66
62.95   44  55  50  49
63  36  55  45  63
63.05   49  53  46  47
63.1    41  40  42  51
63.15   46  41  47  40
63.2    44  33  51  58
63.25   36  45  43  46
63.3    34  49  46  58
63.35   36  42  40  46
63.4    58  62  37  57
63.45   42  51  40  58
63.5    40  54  36  40
63.55   48  52  51  46
63.6    43  39  41  46
63.65   35  50  51  46
63.7    36  39  42  47
63.75   42  51  36  52
63.8    41  43  54  52
63.85   40  53  42  37
63.9    39  51  51  63
63.95   40  59  42  66
64  32  44  32  43
64.05   46  57  39  53
64.1    44  42  38  68
64.15   41  44  57  51
64.2    44  41  41  50
64.25   35  40  30  61
64.3    45  51  36  41
64.35   46  52  44  42
64.4    37  47  44  51
64.45   43  52  46  41
64.5    36  35  47  63
64.55   40  61  41  59
64.6    36  40  40  49
64.65   45  38  53  58
64.7    38  41  44  50
64.75   42  49  44  43
64.8    37  53  42  41
64.85   39  47  42  55
64.9    50  42  35  53
64.95   40  41  43  45
65  28  43  48  46
65.05   34  38  39  42
65.1    41  44  44  45
65.15   42  54  43  49
65.2    40  38  46  33
65.25   45  45  44  54
65.3    34  46  33  48
65.35   44  41  29  32
65.4    49  41  55  46
65.45   49  45  43  58
65.5    46  40  38  56
65.55   36  44  51  50
65.6    40  48  44  45
65.65   51  32  44  38
65.7    30  35  29  42
65.75   48  60  42  64
65.8    34  55  38  44
65.85   52  43  48  56
65.9    32  47  46  56
65.95   43  60  47  50
66  41  44  40  47
66.05   42  51  34  56
66.1    61  49  44  53
66.15   57  57  45  42
66.2    55  52  50  59
66.25   44  50  42  53
66.3    63  83  63  62
66.35   78  75  85  89
66.4    80  103 120 69
66.45   77  103 96  81
66.5    98  112 114 111
66.55   86  76  85  103
66.6    81  99  80  80
66.65   61  95  64  78
66.7    62  69  65  87
66.75   59  66  50  70
66.8    54  51  44  62
66.85   50  56  38  70
66.9    52  61  45  60
66.95   32  42  46  60
67  35  46  51  57
67.05   39  47  40  46
67.1    47  45  45  52
67.15   39  40  39  53
67.2    51  43  37  46
67.25   53  46  44  53
67.3    35  52  45  48
67.35   41  44  42  50
67.4    38  55  25  49
67.45   25  46  40  45
67.5    48  51  45  54
67.55   41  47  41  46
67.6    37  50  38  44
67.65   45  48  45  53
67.7    37  44  39  51
67.75   29  42  61  66
67.8    32  52  45  51
67.85   28  52  46  48
67.9    31  54  35  58
67.95   41  48  46  45
68  33  37  39  45
68.05   44  36  35  52
68.1    48  41  46  52
68.15   39  55  41  64
68.2    46  51  46  47
68.25   49  31  49  50
68.3    39  53  36  47
68.35   40  41  38  48
68.4    50  61  60  44
68.45   40  31  39  55
68.5    54  37  41  33
68.55   44  43  46  51
68.6    35  48  51  54
68.65   31  51  37  55
68.7    46  40  47  52
68.75   28  58  40  44
68.8    38  52  41  56
68.85   29  50  37  50
68.9    34  47  44  46
68.95   43  45  45  53
69  49  42  42  50
69.05   37  51  61  35
69.1    43  41  54  42
69.15   44  40  48  59
69.2    31  35  41  49
69.25   33  49  35  56
69.3    43  52  49  46
69.35   47  56  44  34
69.4    42  47  29  51
69.45   39  51  46  41
69.5    37  36  30  51
69.55   35  42  50  35
69.6    42  47  40  43
69.65   44  45  40  46
69.7    37  48  31  41
69.75   53  47  34  50
69.8    24  49  41  41
69.85   35  33  49  40
69.9    41  32  34  53
69.95   34  37  33  49
70  42  31  29  39
70.05   37  35  35  38
70.1    22  47  31  49
70.15   47  47  37  40
70.2    35  47  42  50
70.25   31  31  34  39
70.3    52  38  35  46
70.35   37  54  38  49
70.4    41  45  41  43
70.45   40  34  37  49
70.5    47  42  41  48
70.55   44  49  42  41
70.6    39  49  50  46
70.65   47  39  35  54
70.7    30  49  34  51
70.75   39  52  40  43
70.8    41  40  32  41
70.85   36  37  32  40
70.9    25  52  45  44
70.95   41  30  47  40
71  33  38  33  58
71.05   35  53  34  34
71.1    32  36  36  53
71.15   35  57  54  45
71.2    38  47  32  39
71.25   45  52  32  59
71.3    45  45  39  43
71.35   57  37  38  42
71.4    41  43  34  49
71.45   30  48  44  48
71.5    28  41  34  45
71.55   34  47  45  42
71.6    42  39  41  43
71.65   41  52  44  57
71.7    32  46  43  51
71.75   25  44  36  48
71.8    43  49  39  45
71.85   45  61  42  41
71.9    33  40  43  57
71.95   34  39  34  42
72  44  42  37  53
72.05   43  44  40  47
72.1    45  38  43  48
72.15   42  37  37  48
72.2    42  41  43  46
72.25   30  36  39  41
72.3    44  40  37  47
72.35   47  34  45  49
72.4    36  54  33  52
72.45   45  42  42  37
72.5    40  38  36  37
72.55   45  54  45  56
72.6    33  55  37  57
72.65   39  47  27  41
72.7    47  39  40  52
72.75   39  30  45  41
72.8    40  39  30  45
72.85   34  56  46  52
72.9    39  39  43  42
72.95   30  48  32  55
73  31  39  27  49
73.05   37  42  40  39
73.1    35  39  42  42
73.15   39  41  45  53
73.2    37  46  36  55
73.25   34  44  46  51
73.3    38  48  32  51
73.35   41  38  48  44
73.4    34  44  36  38
73.45   50  50  45  63
73.5    46  48  49  63
73.55   44  55  54  63
73.6    54  79  45  60
73.65   57  71  77  66
73.7    81  95  79  66
73.75   71  104 103 102
73.8    83  89  78  84
73.85   80  96  77  99
73.9    70  72  64  83
73.95   50  85  66  89
74  61  71  59  78
74.05   39  76  62  79
74.1    58  58  50  71
74.15   46  52  39  66
74.2    33  48  42  72
74.25   40  55  46  59
74.3    41  41  42  47
74.35   38  46  40  44
74.4    48  40  38  39
74.45   49  48  51  44
74.5    46  44  45  52
74.55   39  44  44  61
74.6    46  42  40  48
74.65   43  39  48  44
74.7    31  44  37  52
74.75   37  53  36  56
74.8    32  49  38  58
74.85   32  42  33  39
74.9    44  43  43  39
74.95   34  49  40  46
75  29  45  37  55
75.05   31  43  35  39
75.1    33  46  36  42
75.15   52  28  43  44
75.2    32  49  41  54
75.25   29  38  41  43
75.3    29  39  41  51
75.35   36  44  34  48
75.4    28  49  40  43
75.45   28  43  42  45
75.5    45  40  38  49
75.55   25  53  35  49
75.6    30  51  35  42
75.65   26  47  45  46
75.7    32  46  44  47
75.75   32  44  33  49
75.8    44  50  35  63
75.85   40  44  39  42
75.9    30  41  44  45
75.95   34  48  34  58
76  44  49  36  60
76.05   41  57  37  50
76.1    46  41  39  49
76.15   30  39  32  49
76.2    39  34  34  70
76.25   38  49  34  43
76.3    43  33  33  42
76.35   30  50  39  55
76.4    47  55  33  44
76.45   31  33  37  46
76.5    34  40  37  35
76.55   36  47  34  51
76.6    45  38  50  51
76.65   36  41  34  41
76.7    32  40  36  46
76.75   30  41  44  38
76.8    34  52  43  43
76.85   37  37  36  51
76.9    37  51  43  48
76.95   41  46  40  52
77  37  54  33  54
77.05   30  44  55  44
77.1    40  46  42  49
77.15   47  40  41  40
77.2    34  44  30  60
77.25   44  52  45  49
77.3    35  48  36  36
77.35   41  35  33  47
77.4    33  43  34  51
77.45   36  42  48  56
77.5    29  36  37  53
77.55   38  47  36  51
77.6    32  37  48  41
77.65   45  49  33  56
77.7    34  42  39  43
77.75   29  45  51  51
77.8    36  43  36  41
77.85   33  43  35  46
77.9    35  46  37  50
77.95   34  39  46  40
78  40  35  36  43
78.05   43  37  44  54
78.1    33  55  43  49
78.15   35  42  27  41
78.2    40  51  46  38
78.25   43  47  41  36
78.3    38  32  37  31
78.35   38  44  44  56
78.4    43  33  41  50
78.45   40  45  37  41
78.5    42  35  32  36
78.55   38  39  38  43
78.6    34  48  43  39
78.65   34  33  36  58
78.7    40  28  36  43
78.75   37  59  41  60
78.8    37  47  51  46
78.85   39  30  39  47
78.9    47  46  41  42
78.95   40  42  34  52
79  35  35  40  33
79.05   34  40  42  42
79.1    40  40  49  49
79.15   39  48  39  52
79.2    33  30  41  43
79.25   38  40  50  60
79.3    32  44  34  46
79.35   48  48  26  47
79.4    39  34  45  48
79.45   35  51  39  51
79.5    37  39  32  36
79.55   32  45  38  46
79.6    40  57  37  51
79.65   36  45  44  46
79.7    40  30  53  50
79.75   40  46  33  45
79.8    26  37  44  54
79.85   39  38  30  58
79.9    49  37  35  47
79.95   36  30  31  43
80  43  38  41  45
```

My code is as given below

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour font 'Times-Roman,12' size 5in,8in  
set output "XRD_P3.eps"
##
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 1 lc rgb "black"
set xtics out scale 1.5 
set ytics out scale 1.5
set format y ''
set tics font ",16"
set xlabel "2{/Symbol \161} (deg.)"  font ",16"
set ylabel "Intensity (a.u.)" font ",16"
set key inside right top  
set multiplot layout 4,1 rowsfirst 
##
set yrange [0:1500]
set key title "LiCl-KCl + 6 wt.% H_{2}O" font ",14" 
##
set label 1 '(111)' font ",12" at 24.10, 482 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50, 0.50 rotate by 90
set label 2 '(200)' font ",12" at 28.45, 268 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 3 '(220)' font ",12" at 40.65, 230 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 4 '(400)' font ",12" at 58.85, 104 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -1.00,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 5 '(420)' font ",12" at 66.50, 121 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
##
set label 6 '(111)' font ",12" at 30.20, 196 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 7 '(200)' font ",12" at 35.05, 150 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 8 '(220)' font ",12" at 50.25, 179 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 9 '(311)' font ",12" at 59.75, 94 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 11 '(400)' font ",12" at 73.75, 112 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
##
set label 12 '(101)' font ",12" at 21.70, 1116 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "#006400" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
##
set label 13 'LiCl' font ",14" at 72, 1200 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset 2,-0.10
set label 14 'KCl' font ",14" at 72, 1100 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset 2,-0.10 
set label 15 'LiClO_{4}' font ",14" at 72, 1000 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "#006400" offset 2,-0.10 
##
plot [10:80] 'XRD_P3.dat' u 1:5 w l ls 1 notitle
##
##
set yrange [0:300] 
set key title "LiCl-KCl (Vacuum dried)" font ",14" 
##
set label 1 '(222)' font ",12" at 50.30, 195 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50, 0.50 rotate by 90
set label 2 '(200)' font ",12" at 28.45, 198 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 3 '(220)' font ",12" at 40.60, 195 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 4 '(400)' font ",12" at 58.75, 91  point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -1.00,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 5 '(420)' font ",12" at 66.40, 130 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
##
set label 6 '(111)' font ",12" at 30.20, 137 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 7 '(200)' font ",12" at 34.95, 114 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 9 '(311)' font ",12" at 59.65, 92 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 10 '(222)' font ",12" at 62.75, 70 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 11 '(400)' font ",12" at 73.75, 113 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
##
set label 12 'LiCl' font ",14" at 72, 250 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset 2,-0.10
set label 13 'KCl' font ",14" at 72, 220 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset 2,-0.10 
##
plot [10:80] 'XRD_P3.dat' u 1:4 w l ls 1 notitle
##
##
set yrange [0:350] 
set key title "LiCl-KCl (Chlorinated)" font ",14" 
##
set label 2 '(200)' font ",12" at 28.40, 267 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 3 '(220)' font ",12" at 40.60, 193 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 4 '(400)' font ",12" at 58.70, 85  point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -1.00,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 5 '(420)' font ",12" at 66.50, 122 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
##
set label 6 '(111)' font ",12" at 30.20, 169 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 7 '(200)' font ",12" at 35.05, 152 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 8 '(220)' font ",12" at 50.30, 172 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 9 '(311)' font ",12" at 59.80, 107 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 10 '(222)' font ",12" at 62.60, 82 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
set label 11 '(400)' font ",12" at 73.75, 114 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset -0.50,0.50 rotate by 90
##
set label 12 'LiCl' font ",14" at 72, 300 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "blue" offset 2,-0.10
set label 13 'KCl' font ",14" at 72, 270 point pt 7 ps 1.75 lt rgb "red" offset 2,-0.10 
##
plot [10:80] 'XRD_P3.dat' u 1:3 w l ls 1 notitle
##
##
unset multiplot
```

In the plot, there are random texts appearing outside the XRD patterns, and in some cases the labels are rotated. PNG version of the plot is attached.

Comment: Could you please show your exact output graph? Try a `reset session` at the beginning. Some "ghost-labels" might already disappear.

Comment: Thank you. ```reset session``` does not seem to work. Plot in PNG form is attached.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Yes. it did. Thank you.

Comment: Then, please accept the answer in order to mark your question as solved. Thanks on StackOverflow = accpet and/or upvote.

Comment: Question answered...?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of labels persists in a multiplot environment. It's somewhere in the documentation but I haven't found it right away in `help label`.

Here is some code to illustrate your "problem".
In the second plot `label 4` and `label 5` are not defined explicitely, but the definition still exists in memory from the first plot. Hence, label 4 and label 5 will be drawn at the second plot's coordinates `4,4` and `5,5` which are located somewhere in the first plot.

So, either you explicitly unset them `unset label 4` and `unset label 5` or you unset all labels `unset label` and newly define all desired labels.

**Code:**

```
### setting/unsetting of labels
reset session

set xrange [0:8]
set multiplot layout 2,1

    set label 1 at 1,1 "Label1a"
    set label 2 at 2,2 "Label2a"
    set label 3 at 3,3 "Label3a"
    set label 4 at 4,4 "Label4a"
    set label 5 at 5,5 "Label5a"
    plot x
    # unset label      # uncomment this line to reset all labels

    set label 1 at 1,-1 "Label1b"
    set label 2 at 2,-2 "Label2b"
    set label 3 at 3,-3 "Label3b"
    plot -x

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]